# Need to take multiple digit input from a string removing spaces and alphabets

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a program where I am taking string as an input, here I need to remove spaces , ignore alphabets and use only numerals.

I am able to achieve removing spaces and alphabets, but i can only use single digits and not multiple digits.

Example:Input string:"adsf 12af 1 a123c 53c2m34n"

Here I need to use the input as "12 1 123 54234" required for my application.

It will be great some one could share the logic or the sample code for the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing the code you have already written, we can't tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Your question statement isn't clear.  You say you need to remove spaces, but you need to use your input string as `"12 1 123 54234"`?

Comment: The ctype.h standard header file can help you. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Character-Handling).

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer earlier,
with input string as : "adsf 12af 1 a123c 53c2m34n"
i need to use input as something like this 
arr[]={12,1,123,54234} ignoring "adsf" altogether and so are the remaining alphabets and spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int pullOut(const char *str, int array[], int *size){
    const char *p = str, *endp;
    int pull, count = 0, max = *size, num;

    do{
        endp=strchr(p, ' ');
        if(endp == NULL)
            endp=strchr(p, '\0');

        for(num=pull=0; p != endp; ++p){
            if(isdigit(*p)){
                num = num * 10 + *p - '0';
                pull = 1;
            }
        }
        if(pull && count < max)
            array[count++] = num;

        while(*p == ' ')
            ++p;//skip sapce
    }while(*endp != '\0');

    return *size = count;
}

int main(void){
    char input[] = "adsf 12af   1 a123c 53c2m34n abc def";
    int i, arr[128] = { 0 }, arr_num = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

    pullOut(input, arr, &arr_num);

    for(i = 0; i < arr_num ; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
can u plz help with pushing the above int array on to stack( with the user defined size), with the foll. implementation of push for string,
Plz suggest changes for int array or let me know if the structure defined is wrong

typedef int stack_elmnt_int;
typedef char stack_elmnt;

typedef struct {
  stack_elmnt *s1;
  stack_elmnt_int *s3;
  int length;
  int top;
} stack;

void push_stack_int(stack *stack_ptr, stack_elmnt_int element)
{
 int i=0;
 
 if (stack_full(stack_ptr))
  printf("\nStack is full.");
 else
  *stack_ptr->s1[++stack_ptr->top] = element;
}

Comment: what can i replace it with?

Answer (score 1):

here is your func:

```
void remove_func(char *str)
{
int i;

i = 0;
while(str[i])
{
if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
{
putchar(str[i]);
i++;
}
else if(str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] != ' ')
{
putchar(str[i]);
i++;
}
else
i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;int j = 0;
while (input[i])
{
  if (input[i] == ' ' || (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9'))
     newString[j++] = input[i];
  i++;
}
newString[j] = '\0';
```

If you do this, you'll copy only numerics and space into newString. I let you do all the memory alloc stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one:

```
char * getNumbers(const char *src, char *dst)
{
    int j=0,i=0;
    while (i < strlen(src))
    {
        if (src[i] >= '0' && src[i] <= '9') 
        {
            dst[j++]=src[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            // skip duplicates spaces
            if (j > 0 && src[i] == ' ' && dst[j-1] != ',') dst[j++]=',';
            i++;
        }
    }
    // remove the trailing ',' if exists
    if (j > 0 && dst[j-1] == ',') j--; 
    dst[j]='\0';
    return dst;
}


char src[] = "adsf 12af 1 a123c 53c2m34n";
char dst[sizeof(src)];
getNumbers(src, dst);

printf("'%s' -> '%s'\n", src, dst);
```

output:
'adsf 12af 1 a123c 53c2m34n' -> '12,1,123,53234'